# Does va_end(args) cause crash?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Our server processes keep crashing after we migrated from 32-bit to 64-bit.  The coredump always points to the line with "}"  after call to va_end ( args );

```
428                 // Reset the arg pointer
429                 va_end ( args );
430             }   <-------
431
```

I'm guessing that the cause of this crash is because of the passing of va_list 'args' from one function to another?

The code is quite big so I will just summarize the flow. The functions receives a variable number of arguments used to print to a logfile. Basically just as a logging function.
The va_list args is being passed very deep into nested functions, is there a potential cause for crash here? see below:

```
void logGeneric(string file, int line, ...)
{
  try
  {
   va_list args;
   va_start(args,line);
   function1(file,line,args);
   va_end(args);
  }
  catch(...)
  {
   va_end(args);
  } <---- coredump points to here.
}

void function1(string file, int line, va_list args)
{
   function2(file,line,args);
}
void function2(string file, int line, va_list args)
{
   function3(file,line,args);
}
void function3(string file, int line, va_list args)
{
   completeMessage(file,line,args);
}
void completeMessage(string file, int line, va_list args)
{
int level = va_arg ( args, int );
char* format = "";
    format =va_arg(args,char*);
    ...(checking)...
    char buff[Maxsize+1];
    int ret=vsnprintf(buff,Maxsize, format, args);
    ...(checking)...
    message = buff;
    printToFile(message,line,level);

}
```

In the 32-bit version the function signature for completeMessage is:

```
 void completeMessage (string& file, int line, va_list& args);
```

But because we used a newer gcc, there's a compilation error:

```
 src/DebugUtil.cpp:995: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'GenericLogType'
 src/GenericLogType.h:45: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'GenericLogType':
 src/ILogType.h:117: note:       virtual std::string ILogType::getCompleteLogMessage(const std::string&, int, __
 va_list_tag*)
```

To solve that compilation error I just changed the function to:

```
void completeMessage (string& file, int line, va_list args);
```

Will the passing of the args argument cause any crash?  Or the core file might be totally off because it's in release mode...

My gcc version = 4.4.7

CENTOS 6.4 Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

Comment: The line above your arrow shouldn't compile. `std::va_list` shouldn't be passed by value as it can be an array type.

Comment: it is very likely that you have a problem somewhere else. Have you tried `valgrind`ing it?

Comment: It would be also helpful if you come up with a small complete example that shows this behavior and post it here so we can try and debug it.

Comment: Shouldn't that not compile since `args` is out of scope?